# Setting log priority for Nodejs app running as systemd service

Tags: node.js, systemd

I have an application which is running as a systemd service.

Logs can be accessed using journalctl which is what I want, however despite the fact that node logs console.error > stderr, it does not seem possible to identify console.error from console.log entries using the -p(riority) filter.

It seems that all logs are sent without a priority:

```
journalctl -fu my-app.* -p 3
```

Attempting to show error logs ( p=3) results in no logs, despite the fact that there are error logs.

How can I go about configuring nodejs to output it's logs with a priority level so that I can filter error and normal log files using journalctl ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by prepending the `<priority>` to all logs with this:

```
function jclogs(){
  
  var levels = {
    alert   : 1,
    error   : 3,
    warn    : 4,
    info    : 6,
    log     : 7
  }
  
  for(var level in levels){
    const pri = levels[level];
    console[level] = function(...args) {
      var line = [`<${pri}>`];
      args.map(function(arg){
        if(typeof arg != 'string') try {arg = JSON.stringify(arg)} 
        catch(e){};
        line.push(arg); 
      })
      process.stdout.write(`${line.join(' ')}\n`); 
    }
  }
}
```

It also attempts to stringify any data.